# Why is mysql data not pulling into form despite query finding record, does look up value need to be unique?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms

I have the following code which is supposed to pull data from mysql database if search box value matches row & attribute Client_Name in MYSQL.

please see http://www.recruitingblt.comli.com/add-new-sales-record.html.

When a match is found, the form reverts back (try James Dean) and does not autopopulate the fields I want it to (for now I am just asking for Client_Address, Client_Phone & Attn_Email1  to test). These are the names of columns in mysql table `bltrecruiting`).

I am thinking that maybe Client_Name needs to be unique, say I have company Microsoft, and there is more than one row, will the query not be able to pull through address, phone etc despite being the same for all Microsoft records? Does the look up value need to be unique?

```
<?php
$regnum = $_GET['regnum']; 
//////////regnum is named box at top of form page (Client Name Box) 

//////Connection which seems to work fine 
$db_host = 'mysql6.000webhost.com';
$db_username = '********';
$db_password = '********';
$db_name = 'a8748341_bltrec';

mysql_connect( $db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name); 

////// Check for the Client Name which is a field Client_Name in the database - Should Client_Name be unique? 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bltrecruiting WHERE Client_Name='$regnum'") or
die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
if (empty($row[Client_Name]))
{
        echo "No previous record of Client: $regnum <br>";
        echo "Please try again <br>" ?>

        <div id=regcon>
            <FORM NAME = "reg" action=database.php>
            <div style=width:150px; float:left; display:inline-block; font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 12px; padding-left:13px;> Client Name: </div>

            <input type="text" id="textbox" name="regnum" size="20"/>
            <input name="Submit"  type="submit" value="Get Form"/>

            </form>
        </div>
 }
else
{
///////// Get the fields from the database
    $address = $row['Client_Address'];
    $phonenumber = $row['Client_Phone'];
    $name= $row['Attn_Name1'];
    //add your additional fields here


    echo '<script    type="text/javascript"src="http://form.jotform.com/jsform/43438603456356?"Client_Name='.$regnum.'&Client_Address='.$address.'&Client_Phone='.$phonenumber.'&Attn_Name1='.$name.'"></script>';


}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When running an error.php page I get this; Notice: Undefined index: regnum in /home/a8748341/public_html/database.php on line 9  . This is line 9; $regnum = $_GET['regnum'];              regnum is the name of the search field......anyone help please?

Comment: Ideally yes you do want a unique company name but if you want to test your script add 'limit 1' to your mysql query - that will return 1 row only.

Comment: Are you aiming to return only 1 result right?

Comment: hi @PHPology yes exactly just one, as there maybe many entries with that client name in the future, I just want one result to pre-populate the rest of the fields, as the one result will be the same for all entries. So I add 'limit 1' after $'regnum'? Thank you in advance

Comment: @PHPology I just read the manual on LIMIT 1, it makes sense so I've added it to the query after $'regnum' but still nothing, I think this is on the right track though, I will keep trying. Here is my current query ("SELECT * FROM bltrecruiting WHERE Client_Name='$regnum' LIMIT 1")

Comment: just an FYI, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  I would very much  consider using PDO with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

i noticed that your empty($row[Client_Name]) did not have quotes around it but I tested the below code. Even tho you might have more than 1 row, your $row variable will have data for row 1 in its index (you are not doing a while loop thru the mysql_fetch_array).

```
if (!is_array($row) && empty($row['Client_Name']))
    {
            echo "No previous record of Client: $regnum <br>";
            echo "Please try again <br>";
    ?>

        <div id=regcon>
            <FORM NAME = "reg" action=database.php>
            <div style=width:150px; float:left; display:inline-block; font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 12px; padding-left:13px;> Client Name: </div>

            <input type="text" id="textbox" name="regnum" size="20"/>
            <input name="Submit"  type="submit" value="Get Form"/>

            </form>
        </div>
<?php
 }
else
{
    ///////// Get the fields from the database
    $address = $row['Client_Address'];
    $phonenumber = $row['Client_Phone'];
    $name= $row['Attn_Name1'];
    //add your additional fields here

    echo '<script type="text/javascript"src="http://form.jotform.com/jsform/43438603456356?"Client_Name='.$regnum.'&Client_Address='.$address.'&Client_Phone='.$phonenumber.'&Attn_Name1='.$name.'"></script>';
}
```

i did a test locally and faked some values into the javascript URL - should they appear in that form?

Comment: Yes the form in the java URL, when I take LIMIT 1 out, and search by client name it returns back to the form but doesn't pull any data through. When I have Limit 0 or LIMIT 1 in the query, it doesn't find the record, any ideas? I've added in the if array as I can see now why that is important. I've also taken out fields so it just pulls through one data field from the database Attn_Email1 to simplify the string to test, but still no luck.

Comment: http://pastie.org/9788368 @Katie - try what i did please. p.s. kinda did this blind so might throw errors

Comment: Hi @PHpology I've tried your script, no errors at all, when I search for a name that is in the database it just reverts to the form but doesn't pull data through....I am baffled!!

Comment: did the sql print out? did you run that? did the print_r($row) give you anything too?

Comment: sorry you've lost me, where do I incorporate print_r($row)? its not in my php running this query?? sorry @PHPology

Comment: the client's name prints onto the screen when it doesn't find a record, i.e. it says client name 'Adam Price' not found....so it's going through the query, is that what you mean? Please forgive me I am lost!!

Comment: Ahh maybe you did not see my pastebin link then: http://pastie.org/9788368#24 - ive got an echo $sql and print_r($row)

Comment: sorry you did see my link - but i tried to output some results to help test

Comment: yes I missed your pastie I am sorry! I've updated the code and now I get the array yes! Exactly how it is in the table, it prints out but still nothing in the form.......@PHPology you are a legend for helping with this!!

Comment: Here is what it prints out...everything is fine no errors, but just nothing in the form, SELECT * FROM bltrecruiting WHERE Client_Name='James Dean' limit 1

Array ( [0] => 294593822742985816 [submission_id] => 294593822742985816 [1] => 43438603456356 [formID] => 43438603456356 [2] => 31.54.182.47 [IP] => 31.54.182.47 [3] => Freelance [Placement] => Freelance [4] => James Dean [Client_Name] => James Dean etc etc I've just noticed Freelance [4] is not in mysql, do you think that is something to do with it? thanks

Comment: I think that we are passing in the values into the Javascript URL but jotform.com does not know what to do with your values. Are you allowed to prepopulate the fields like how you done? DO yo know if its even possible?

Comment: they gave sample scripts how to do it on their website, using the method I have used, so I am presuming so..... [link] (http://www.jotform.com/answers/68107-I-have-a-database-with-all-information-that-my-jotform-will-be-asking-t) I guess this means its working it is just jot form I will try and ask one of their support, thank you for your help if you think of anything else please please let me know

Comment: ahh ok ok -  ya maybe speak to them too. Just check the source tho to ensure we are populating the fields in the URL

Comment: the good news is I got the data pulling through, but now it only pulls through the resulting attn_name1 from the first row in mysql table. I have tried changing the limit from 0 and 10, get the same result. Also, it only populates the first field, so attn_email1 is going in my client name field (first field on my form). Here is my modified code [link](http://pastie.org/9788625). The name fields in the Java bit are taken directly from my form source, is it because they are named so similar would you recommend changing the names?